# Is it enough to attribute CC licensed media through a URL only?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I have made some videos for computer education.

I might be sale it in future...

I have used images which comes under
[creative commons](https://creativecommons.org/) and from [pixbay](https://pixabay.com/) license.

I want to know is that compulsory to give credits for that images in my video.

Right now I  have shown the URL's at the end of video, from where I have downloaded these images.

Is that ok to put the URLS ?

Comment: Which CC licence(s)?

Comment: It is often better to ask about Creative Commons licenses at [opensource.se], but you do need to be explicit about which CC license you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

From pixbay:

> All images and videos on Pixabay are released free of copyrights under
>   **Creative Commons CC0**. You may download, modify, distribute, and use
>   them royalty-free for anything you like, even in commercial
>   applications. **Attribution is not required**.

So you need to figure out which CC license your other photos carry and comply.